# Understanding HTML elements to select a certain date in Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I am writing some code that will locate the release date of an earnings report. I am running into an issue where I am not able to select the specific date using Beautiful Soup.

```
import bs4, requests
ticker = TSLA

res = requests.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/earnings/' + ' '.join(ticker))
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

elems = soup.select('time sidebar-recent__event__date')

please = elems.getText()
```

[image: Screenshot of Inspect information for the part I want to select]

Could you help me to find what is the correct HTML element that I need to put into the `select()` function to select that information? Also could explain the reason behind why you selected that HTML element to do that?

I tried:

```
elems = soup.select('sidebar-recent__event__date')

elems = soup.select('.sidebar-recent__event__date')

elems = soup.select('time sidebar-recent__event__date')

elems = soup.select('sidebar-recent__event__date time')
```

Attached is the website that I am using if you want to inspect the elements.

https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/tsla

Answer (score 0):

From doc;

```
soup.select(".sister")
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

so for your question it should be

```
elems = soup.select('time.sidebar-recent__event__date')
```

There’s also a method called `select_one()`, which finds only the first tag that matches a selector:

```
soup.select_one(".sister")
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors